# Should simple helper methods be a private instance method, class category or something else all together?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, methods

I have tons of little helper functions such as this littered throughout my view controller classes to help me accomplish things I do repeatedly:

```
- (BOOL)URLIsImgurAlbum:(NSURL *)URL {
    // If the URL has "/a/" after the imgur portion it's an album.
    if ([[URL.path substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)] isEqualToString:@"/a/"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

I feel like this is... wrong, though. Like there's a better place to put it as it's not really relevant to the view controller itself, but some of the content it's handling. I'm not using it in other classes or anything, so it's not copy and pasted across files, but still.

Would it be better as a category on NSURL (in the above case)? Something else all together?

Answer (score 1):

You can make them as regular C-style functions outside of classes too:

```
BOOL URLIsImgurAlbum(NSURL *URL) {
    return [[URL.path substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)] 
        isEqualToString:@"/a/"];
}
```

Comment: Assuming that the functions are private, consider making them `static`.

Comment: and what's the benefit for making them "`static`", @dasblinkenlight?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Their names would not "pollute" the global namespace, preventing potential collisions when linking your code.

Comment: What's the benefit of this method?

Comment: The benefit of using C-style functions?  Or the benefit of not making them static?

Comment: What is the benefit of this versus doing it with the code I posted?

Comment: It's is ever so slightly better from a performance standpoint, but you'd never ever notice the performance difference.  The syntax is a little different, which you may or may not like, but it requires less typing.  And this doesn't have to be a part of the class.